# Echoing PHP Array Returns no Result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, echo

So, guys, my problem is that i'm creating an array from a mysql column, but, when i echo the array items, it returns me nothing, i'm about this for a while and i'm not seeing a possible error, hope can get some help. Here' s my code: (I know about the mysql to mysqli, but i'm just beginning and trying the logical stuff. :))

```
$duracao = mysql_query(
    "SELECT SUM(fim_periodo-inicio_periodo)/0.01666667 AS mysum
 FROM afunda_eleva_$a"
); //THIS $duracao IS INSIDE A FOR LOOP THAT EXECUTES THE QUERY IF A CONDITION IS SATISFIED (DEPENDING ON $a and $prevNum), it is working fine!

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($duracao))
{
    $duracao_afunda_eleva[] = $row2['mysum'];
}
```

so, to test some possible problems, i've put:

```
$i2 = sizeof($duracao_afunda_eleva);    
echo $i2;
echo <br>;
```

which returns me the right size of the array, the problem comes here, i think:

```
for($i1 = 0 ; $i1 < sizeof($duracao_afunda_eleva); $i1++)    
{
    echo $duracao_afunda_eleva[$i1] or die("couldn't echo"
    . mysql_error());        
    echo "<br>";    
}
```

and this returns me no value. I really would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var_dump($duracao_afunda_eleva)` will show you EXACTLY what's in that array.

Comment: Hmm, that gave me a good result, but not happy one, all the values of the array are NULL. :S I think the problem might be on the point where i get the values on the array. Thanks!

Comment: but it's kinda weird, cause the size of the array is ok! But the values, not, so i think that: <br>while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($duracao))
    {
    $duracao_afunda_eleva[] = $row2['mysum'];
    } <br> is working somehow. I'll try something around here.

Comment: so your query is running right, but returning sql NULLs for all those records. e.g. your sum is failing somehow.

Comment: I see, i'll try some coding here, i get back if i get something. :) Thx.

Comment: Finally i could find the error! i was getting really NULL values with my where condition, cause this WHERE i've used already in a query before this to get to table, so it was unnecessary here. Thanks for the vardump! I'll edit the right code for further counsults.

Answer (score 0):

Try [print_r](http://php.net/manual/de/function.print-r.php) instead of echo - echo outputs (string)$variable, which in case of an array is just "array". Also, echo is a language construct and not a function, so your `or die(...)` is problematic, as language constructs don't have return values.

Generally it's better to not use `or die(...)` constructs, and handle problems correctly (using a defined return value, so cleanup code can run, for example). Also, not being able to output anything with echo would mean that your php/whatever installation is seriously gone bad, at which point you probably won't even reach that line in your code, and even then it won't have anything to do with mysql.

Comment: Hmm, i see. I was just trying the die command in order to look for a possible problem. Thanks for  the tips, i'll keep track of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is not in the variable, try to use an alias in your MySQL select:

```
SELECT SUM(fim_periodo-inicio_periodo)/0.01666667 as mysum
```

Then in your PHP, you can get `$row2['mysum']`;
It may not solve the problem, but it is a good start.

Comment: Ops, i'm sorry, it was a mistyping. On code, the variable is the right!

Comment: Please update your code for the variable, and the alias so that people can see it better.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
for($i1 = 0 ; $i1 < sizeof($duracao_afunda_eleva); $i1++)    
{
   echo $duracao_afunda_eleva[$i1] or die("couldn't echo". mysql_error());        
   echo "<br>";    
}
```

You increased `$i` instead of `$i1`.

Although, with arrays, it's usually easier to use a `foreach` loop.
This runs from the first to the last element in the array.

Like so:

```
foreach ($duracao_afunda_eleva as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

I would also suggest removing the space in `$row2 ['mysum']`:

```
$duracao_afunda_eleva[] = $row2['mysum'];
```

**Edit**

Just noticed it now, but your fetch-statement is wrong... It has a typo in it:

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($duracao))
```

Make sure it reads `mysql` instead of `myqsl`.

Comment: Hmm, ok, this foreach is really "cleaner". I've made all the changes, but still got no results though. Thx for the tips

Comment: @GustavoxD I've edited this answer, because I've only just saw a typo... Perhaps that'll fix the error.

Comment: It was another mistyping, my bad. On code, it was typed right.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use:

```
$arr = array ( /* ... */ );
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: (-1) http://php.net/manual/function.var-dump.php does not return anything, so the additional echo is pretty useless. Also, echo is not a function, so you can do without parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the info on var_dump. I personally have used parenthesis on echo in the past just because it looked cleaner for me.

Answer (score 0):

A quick tip is not to use the `sizeof` function in your `for` loop. This gets run with each iteration of your loop and you will notice an improvement in performance if you move it outside the loop (or use a `foreach` loop instead). e.g.

```
$count = sizeof($duracao_afunda_eleva);
for($i = 0 ; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $duracao_afunda_eleva[$i] . '<br />';
}
```

or

```
// Foreach loop example
foreach ($duracao_afunda_eleva as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . '<br />';
}
```

or what you could also do is this one line

```
echo implode('<br />', $duracao_afunda_eleva);
```

Comment: just a sidenote: sizeof() is an alias to count(). (I prefer count(), as sizeof is for example also used in C, and while it would do more or less the same on statically defined arrays, php does not have those besides http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php which not many people actually seem to know/use ...)

Answer (score 0):

In your last for-loop, you use $i++, it should be $i1++